# Unable to resume activity in libGDX

Tags: android, android-activity, libgdx, onresume

I am try to develop an application. It has some activities, these are,
`SplashActivity`,
`MainMenuActivity`, and
`GameActivity`.

Now, all three activities extends `BaseActivity` which also extends `AndroidApplication` of libgdx.

In `SplashActivity` and `MainMenuActivity`, I have written pure android specific code using onCreate, setContentView a layout and etc. I have not write any libgdx code on those activites.

Activity transitions are like this,
SplashActivity (it gets finish) -> MainMenuActivity (not get finished) -> GameActivity

On, GameActivity, I setContentView mygame layout, and, write this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mygame);

      gbbrdlyot1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.gbbrdlyot1);
      gameBoard = new RelativeLayout(this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newBlockWidth, newBlockWidth);
      gameBoard.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

      View gameView = initializeForView(new GameView(), true);
      gameBoard.addView(gameView);   

        gbbrdlyot1.addView(gameBoard);
}
```

But I am getting RuntimeException on SplashActivity, I dont know why,

```
    05-27 12:56:22.609:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity com.game.MyGame/com.game.MyGame.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 12:56:22.609:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
05-27 12:56:22.609:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
05-27 12:56:22.609:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-27 12:56:22.609:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 12:56:22.609: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:249)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.game.MyGame.SplashActivity.onResume(SplashActivity.java:43)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
05-27 12:56:22.609: ... 12 more
```

Comment: Just as P.T. said, your SplashActivity didn't initialized libgdx, you can see line 249 of AndroidApplication is ((AndroidInput)getInput()).registerSensorListeners(); The input is initialized when you call AndroidApplication#initialize(..) which you didn't call in SplashActivity#onCreate(), that's why NullPointerException is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the stack trace:

```
05-27 12:56:22.609: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:249)
05-27 12:56:22.609: at com.game.MyGame.SplashActivity.onResume(SplashActivity.java:43)
```

Implies that your `SplashActivity` extends the Libgdx `AndroidApplication`.  But you wrote:

> In SplashActivity, MainMenuActivity, I have written pure android
>   specific code using onCreate, setcontentView a layout and etc. I have
>   not write any libgdx code on that activities.

But, if you're extending `AndroidApplication` you're getting a bunch of Libgdx code that runs at pause and resume time.  But you haven't initialized Libgdx yet (since that seems to happen as a side-effect of your `GameActivity`'s creation.

Keep your pure Android activities pure, and do not extend the Libgdx classes.